# Cut information from html (on javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

Sorry for kind of a dumb question, but I haven't found a good manual. I get some html content using the following code:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://someurl.net", false);
xhr.send();
var resp = xhr.responseText;
```

Then I need to get content which lies between tags content, but I don't know how to do it. I would appreciate any help

Comment: This is much easier with jQuery.

Comment: @RobW: HTML parsing is not a basic string operation.

Comment: you know that after your code, resp is going to be empty, right? you have to set up a call back to wait for the response

Comment: Just take a note AJAX wont work if your trying to request any other domain other than script is originating from (browser CSRF limitation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the result of your ajax call, you need to handle the `onreadystatechange` event:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        var result = xhr.responseText;
    }
}
```

---

The easiest way to get / set content between tags is to give your element an id:

```
<div id="myDiv">Hi There</div>
```

And then in your script:

```
var div = document.getElementById("myDiv");
//get content:
var currentContent = div.innerHTML;
//set content:
div.innerHTML = "New Content";
```

---

If this is an actual project you're working on, and not just a learning exercise, I'll mention that making ajax calls and updating your dom is much, much easier with jQuery.  It'll cut down your code significantly.